# insert xml as blob into mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

I have a JSON file that I parse and `INSERT` values from into a database. The column type in my database is `longblob`. My project is a nodejs application using the [mysql module](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql). The XML is stored as a string in the JSON and I use something similar to:

```
    private insertXMLBlob(file: ILogRecord): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(`INSERT INTO blob_table(myBlob) VALUES(BINARY(${file.myXMLString}))`, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log(results);
                resolve(results.insertId);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This gives me the error:

> ERROR: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '${myXMLString}'

I have also tried using `Buffer.from(file.myXMLString)` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding)) and inserting the buffer directly into my table. I looked at [this example](https://gist.github.com/akirattii/86e2eda8e110976cce144c991e9cada8) which seems out of date. If I am doing something fundamentally wrong with my design (such as the column type) please let me know.

Comment: `BLOB` datatype is meant for BINARY files, XML is plain text use `TEXT` datatype instead

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I am trying to convert the text to binary, which in the example I read used BINARY() function

Comment: " I am trying to convert the text to binary, which in the example I read used BINARY() function" i noticed why making it harder for yourself just use `TEXT` datatype then you won't have to convert it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, this might be a bit of a different question but what are the implications of changing the data type in storage and efficiency?

Comment: "his might be a bit of a different question but what are the implications of changing the data type in storage and efficiency? " Will not matter that much TEXT and BLOB both are equally bad.. in InnoDB they are separated from the other columns data meaning MySQL needs to do a extra disk I/O per record to get the `BLOB` or `TEXT` column from the record.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I changed column type to LONGTEXT and did an insert as `INSERT INTO vehicle_scan (vehicleScan) VALUES(${file.myXMLString})` and it still failed. I now believe there is something wrong with my XML string. The XML is valid format, so I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Maybe the XML is simply to large MySQL has a default max_allowed_packet which is around 4Mb? Which you can adjust.

Answer (score 0):

If `file.myXMLString` is indeed a string then converting it to `Buffer` should be fine. But you seem to convert `myXMLString`, not `file.myXMLString`. Try: `Buffer.from(file.myXMLString)`.

Or use `TEXT` type field and insert directly was suggested in the comments.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, when I tried the Buffer.from() approach, I did use file.myXMLString.